# Is there any way to tell which way an arcane sentry will fire when it starts up?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I predict the direction and arc of an Arcane Sentry?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68627/how-can-i-predict-the-direction-and-arc-of-an-arcane-sentry)

When fighting "Arcane Enchanted" enemies, I notice the little ball of energy a few seconds before it starts to fire.  When it fires, it appears to fire energy in a line that travels through a 360 degree arc, and then it despawns.

However, the direction it starts in matters - I can be standing right next to one for several seconds after it starts to arc, so long as I'm not directly in the line of fire.  I might even be able to stand there for longer, if I'm on the side where it will hit last.

Is there any way to determine which way the sentry will fire when it starts firing?  Does it always travel in the same direction?  (ie, clockwise or counter clockwise?)